# Accidentally deleted a .css file - Which recovery methods shall I try?

Tags: google-chrome, css, browser-cache

This is a bit of a disaster, as it's a 1000+ line CSS file I wrote over a few days for a client. Deadline is tomorrow.

I deleted it from a network path that doesn't go into recycle bins.

The webserver is a Virtual Machine hosted with Microsoft Azure. I run Apache on there.

I have tried the following:

- Checked my Chrome cache, but this was deleted when I refreshed the website
- Checked a colleagues IE cache, but nothing is there
- Ran Recuva on the server, but azure doesn't work like that and the file is gone once deleted
- Searched my whole PC for any copies of the file, but nothing

My only hope (as far as I can see) is working out how to use a colleagues mac to check the Chrome cache on there, or hopefully there is a cache copy on my Laptop at home which I havn't turned on since it was finished.

Is there anything else I could try?

EDIT:

Trying to use Recuva on my collegues PC to restore the Temp files, but only found a bunch of older files.

Trying to work out how to recover temp files from my mobile as I viewed it there too. Not easy!

Comment: It honestly sounds like you are out of luck.

Comment: Long shot, but did you try the low-level recovery? (I forget the term Recuva uses, maybe deep scan or something similar, but it looks for raw file snippets on the platters rather than deleted files).

Comment: @fixer1234 I tried a low level recovery, but Azure uses blob storage and as far as I know you can't recover files the same way, at least they don't provide you access to those recovery methods. I also tried the same on local browser cache to find deleted cache, but no luck.

Comment: Just start writing your code from scratch asap. You might as well manage to get it done before the deadline. Don't waste your time on data recovery. Next time make backups.

Comment: @smc I managed to pull a version from the cache on Google chrome on a laptop that I once viewed the website on in the end. Was the happiest time of my life!

Comment: Glad thet you made it and glad to be wrong. But learn your lesson - take backups seriously from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to recover the file using "ChromeCacheViewer" which is a free software. I ran it on a Laptop that had viewed the website, but not since the file was deleted otherwise Chrome would delete the cache file.

It was slightly out of date, but only 10 minutes of work were needed to bring it up to date.

Lesson learnt, boss wasn't too happy, but is happier now and we will run LiveDrive on the server, aswell as use the 100GB backup option that came with the server!

Answer (score 0):

if you know the perfect path in server where you stored the .css then you use the minitool for the recovery.

---

but must note that don't recover from you pc but from the server.

---

as my opening if you don't want this hark work then you just claim to Microsoft support team about your data.

---

they are always ready for this type of help

Comment: Can't use this to restore from blob storage. Contacted Microsoft support team, they are the worst at support.

Comment: as depends on my perception its not worst its actually very good.

Answer (score -1):

Try turning hidden files on, and looking for local 'recycle bin' files in or near the network path you deleted it from. Hopefully this helps..

Comment: The question states that it was deleted from a network path that doesn't go to recycle bins.  Recycle bins only hold deleted files so a local recycle bin wouldn't have it.

Comment: Checked recycle bin anyway, but the items are permanently deleted form network locations.